# jquery remove class from form elements array

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form with many elements among which several drop menus of this kind:

```
<select name="i_task_user[]" class="required"><option value="">- Select -</option></select>
```

On form load, I would like to remove class **"required"** on all these drop down menus but what I tried so far didn't work.

What I did is: (didn't work)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[name="assign_task_status[]"]').removeClass('required');
});
```

and: (didn't work too)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.each($('form[name="frm"] select[name="assign_task_status[]"]').children(), function(i, elt){
       $(this).removeClass('required');
   });
});
```

Comment: Is it because the element's name is `i_task_user[]` and you're trying to select `assign_task_status[]`?

Comment: @Juhana thx a lot! I didnt realize I was selecting a different field :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/egohax/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[name^=i_task_user]').removeClass('required');
});
```

`^=` means: *"Starts With"* selector

Or use `$('select[name="i_task_user[]"]')` <sub>as mentioned by Juhana</sub>

Comment: That's not necessary. `$('select[name="i_task_user[]"]')` would work just as well.

Comment: @Juhana exactly, thanks for mentioning, I just tried to make it look nice, and speed won't drop much cause of the selector.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another alternative:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[class=required]").removeClass("required");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$("select.required")` be a bit easier...?

Comment: that also, and + what is some fields are not `.required` ?

Comment: This is for required classes, not properties. If some selects do not have a class = "required" then they would not be selected nor need the have the class removed.

Comment: When you down-vote someone, you should have a real reason. THis code works just fine if you would bother to check it properly.